# web scraping script hanging

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a web scraping script that essential:

```
repeats over all website names:
    retrieves image off of website
    adds to dictionary with key as website name
    prints out what number of the list its on (for tracking purposes)
```

However, it takes about 3 seconds usually for it to process each iteration of the loop. But every 75 rounds or so it suddenly stops and hangs for like 10 minutes at a particular iteration, and then it continues. This is really annoying as the script would only take like an hour otherwise. Whenever the hanging occurs, I notice that the terminal heading looks like:

[image]

Wheras when its running normally it looks like:

[image]

with the circular running bar on the side. My guess is that this is just occurring because its having trouble connecting the website. Though my internet speed is very fast. Additionally all the images are of similair sizes. Does anyone know why it might be hanging every once in a while?

Comment: Do at least something like print 'function which is being processed' before each method to let us know where could be the problem. It could be a lot of things in my opinion including things on servers side.

Comment: You need some sort of debugging info to help us out here

Comment: if you're retrieving images from many pages on the same server, your access might be throttled to N requests every M minutes

Comment: I agree with the above posters, it is more likely that the server is slowing you down. It is usually polite when you are scrapping like this, to put a time delay on the requests, say time.sleep(20) or time.sleep(45) or if it is a website with a low amount of resources a lot longer say time.sleep(60) or higher.

Comment: ^ it is all from the same server. That makes a lot of sense because it does suddenly speeo up after a while and goes back to normal.

Comment: However, If i run multiple scripts in parallel and start them at different times, they don't all hang at the same time. Could the server stuff still explain this?

Comment: It could be something else, I dont know. I have had servers, hang on requests before for a long period of time, but i usually am only running one process, for the reasons i gave above. (However if they are a huge company i sometimes run in parallel.)